# Bodyweight exercises too taxing on delts

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, injury-prevention, shoulders

Been doing calesthenics for 3-4 years and have progressed to intermediate and advanced exercises. However, I find that my deltoids seem to be constabtly overworked. Planche, dynamic handstand excercises, different types of push-ups, muscle up, Human flag etc. all seem to work the delts. And creating inflammation due to overwork.

Any advice on how to do advanced calesthenics often enough to progress without putting too much pressure on the shoulders?

Comment: "And creating inflammation due to overwork" - I think you've answered your own question.  Don't overtrain.

Comment: Maybe just add an extra rest day somewhere in your week

Comment: for sure the other comments where right, but how's about your shoulder depression? Do you feel strong with shoulder depressed?